# Multiple where clause on multiple left join tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 mysql tables.

**products** table

```
id, name
```

**product_styles** table

```
id, products_id, attributes_id, attribute_options_id
```

I'm trying to create a shop filter. Each product can have multiple product_styles. But each product_styles row is unique. Product can't have two product_styles with same attributes_id.

For example i have 2 **products**

```
id:1, name:test1
id:2, name:test2
```

For example i have 2 **product_styles**

```
id:1, products_id:1, attributes_id:1, attribute_options_id:1
id:2, products_id:1, attributes_id:2, attribute_options_id:2 
id:3, products_id:2, attributes_id:1, attribute_options_id:3
id:4, products_id:2, attributes_id:3, attribute_options_id:4
```

How can i select for example all product

```
where attribute_options_id = 1 and  attribute_options_id = 1 
and where attributes_id = 2 and attribute_options_id = 2
```

It should return products only if all where clauses match.

It should return only product with id 1 in this example.

Comment: Maybe take a look at how others have asked questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `group by` and a `having` clause.  I like this approach for this type of query ("set-within-sets" queries) because it is quite general.  Here is the general idea:

```
select ps.products_id
from product_styles ps
group by ps.products_id
having sum(attribute_id = 1 and attribute_options_id = 1) > 0 and
       sum(attributes_id = 2 and attribute_options_id = 2) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause looks for a match for one of the attributes.  It does this by counting the number of rows where the conditions are met.  The `> 0` requires that the rows be present.

If you wanted the first, but not the second condition, you could just change the clause to:

```
select ps.products_id
from product_styles ps
group by ps.products_id
having sum(attribute_id = 1 and attribute_options_id = 1) > 0 and
       sum(attributes_id = 2 and attribute_options_id = 2) = 0;
```